# SESSION not working in Google Chrome with session_set_cookie_params

Tags: php, session

My provider gave me a new server for my website, and since then I've been having issues with the login system, more precisely the `SESSION` is not working well (on localhost I have no issues at all).

At first, it didn't work in IE. So I figured out thanks to other input on stackoverflow that I need to add the following code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', mysite.be');
```

This is set as 'no value' in php.ini. But the line above should correct this, and it does work in IE now.

However, with this line added, it doesn't work in Chrome anymore... The `SESSION` is not working over the pages, so the `SESSION` variables have no value on other pages and therefore the login doesn't work in Chrome.

Full code:

```
<?php
session_start();  
//session_name("mysite");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'mysite.be');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
...
```

I also tried session_name, but it didn't help in Chrome. If I remove `session_set_cookie_params` it works in Chrome but not in IE anymore.

Anyone knows what I am missing? Or should I ask the provider to change the php.ini (Master Value) to `mysite.be` ? I'm not sure this will change anything.

EDIT:
I also have `HTTPS://` now

Comment: Try calling `session_set_cookie_params` before `session_start`.

Comment: @amphetamachine I tried this but it still doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: @amphetamachine do you mean 'mysite.be/' ?

Comment: Try `.mysite.be` with an initial `.`

Comment: @Nicolas. That's the domain parameter,not a path, it shouldn't have `/`

Comment: @Barmar I tried with the . but also not working in Chrome

Comment: Can you see the `PHPSESSID` cookie in the console?

Comment: @Barmar I checked in the console and while removing the cookies.. it worked. A bit embarrassing but seems like I just had to remove my old cookies. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

Use `.mysite.be` as domain if you want it to work on all subsites.
And always remove your cache (old cookies) before trying again. For me it didn't work because of old cookies.